# Solution targeting .NET Core 2.1 builds with old System.ServiceModel.Primitives and System.Private.ServiceModel

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, .net-core-2.1

I have a solution made up of projects targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.1.304. When built this solution utilizes old vulnerable versions of `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` and `System.Private.ServiceModel` ([CVE-2018-0786](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-0786)).

I am probably missing something obvious about the configuration of the overall solution or one of the projects that is causing the utilization of the old versions, but everything I know to check looks correct:

### Global.json

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.302"
  }
}
```

### Example .NET Core Project File

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <Configurations>Debug;Dev;Qual;Release</Configurations>
  <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

### Example .NET Standard Project File

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  <Configurations>Debug;Dev;Qual;Release</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have ensured all NuGet packages are up to date. That said is it possible that one of my NuGet package references is causing a fallback to the old versions? What other configurations should I be checking?

---

<sub>Interestingly when I build a different, but similarly configured solution (from what I can tell) that solution produces a build using the newer non vulnerable versions.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool such as [dotnet-outdated](https://github.com/jerriep/dotnet-outdated) to determine both your the versions of your dependencies and transitive dependencies in your project.

Install via `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated` on the powershell command line
and run `dotnet outdated -t -td 100` in your solution folder to see 100 levels of transitive dependencies.

Your output will look something like the following

```
» MyProject
  [.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1]
  System.Private.ServiceModel [T]                 4.4.0  -> 4.5.3
  System.ServiceModel.Primitives [T]              4.4.0  -> 4.5.3
```

You can then use the above stated out of date dependencies to track down which project(s) in your solution needs to be further investigated.

From there eliminate dependencies that are known to be safe, as they appear in other projects that don't have a dependency on the bad library (regardless of version). At this point it may be a matter of using [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) and investigating each suspect dependency to see what version of sub-dependencies it uses.

Comment: Your answer sent me down a path to a solution. Ultimately, one of the packages that both solutions referenced was the culprit. However, the non vulnerable solution also referenced a package which caused it to pick up a later non vulnerable version of `System.ServiceModel.Primitives`. In addition to dotnet-outdated an excellent tool for determining how an outdated reference was added to your solution is [dotnet-depends](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-depends/). Sadly it currently works on a per project instead of per solution basis but is still very useful.